# mysqli_stmt::get_result() not working, PHP version updated and mysqlnd enabled

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a php class/function that allow me to perform a query on the DB and then return an associative array of the result.

Everything works perfectly fine on my local development environment (MAMP).

Once I moved the site on a godaddy Linux Shared Hosting I get the following error: **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in **/home/username/public_html/dev.x-matcher.com/admin/classes/c_RequeteSQL.php** on line **146**

I have followed the following article(https://ca.godaddy.com/help/enable-custom-php-modules-12036) in order to change the PHP version from 5.4 native to 5.4 and therefore enable the mysqlnd custom extension.

[Godaddy CPANEL - Select PHP Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx8LY.jpg)

Once activated the error **disapears** but the script still blocks at the same place, so still not working.

I have also tried to keep the 5.4 native version of PHP and upload a custom php.ini file in which I added the following line : extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.so and still not working...

I have read a lot of thread like this one(stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result) but could'nt find any solution to my problem.

I understand that I could use **bind_param** and **fetch** to counter the problem but I do not want to do so as My function need to dynamically fetch the results in an associative array and then return the array. Using bind_param forces my to enter the variables and since the number of returned variables are never the same depending on the request it not the solution I am looking for..

You can see my phpinfo if you follow this link: dev.x-matcher.com/phpinfo.php

As explained my whole coding works 100% on my local environment but here is my class just in case:

```
class RequeteSQL {
    private $dbhost = 'localhost';
    private $dbuser = 'user';
    private $dbpass = 'pass';


    function retourArray($requete,$lettres,$parametres){

        global $dbhost;
        global $dbuser;
        global $dbpass;
        $basededon = "db";

        $connection = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$basededon);
        $statement = $connection->prepare($requete);
        if ($statement === false) {
            trigger_error('Probleme avec la requete SQL :' . $requete . ' Erreur code : ' . $connection->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        } else {
            if ($parametres!=NULL) {
                if (is_array($parametres)) {

                    $a_params = array();
                    $param_type = '';
                    $n = count($lettres);
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
                        $param_type .= $lettres[$i];
                    }

                    $a_params[] = & $param_type;

                    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
                        $a_params[] = & $parametres[$i];
                    }

                    call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $a_params);
                } else {
                    $statement->bind_param($lettres,$parametres);
                }

            }

            $statement->execute();
            $resultat = $statement->get_result();
            $resultarray = $resultat->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $statement->close();
            $connection->close();

            return $resultarray;
        }
    }

    function __destruct(){

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong on the server so php_mysqli_mysqlnd is not working OR is there a hosting service that DO supports this extension?

Comment: What do you mean with "the script still blocks at the same place". No errors? What happens?

Comment: Yes it is really weird. The following error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/username/public_html/dev.x-matcher.com/admin/classes/c_RequeteSQL.php on line 146" just disapears but no improvement it's stops at the same place. (*I am sorry english is not my first lenguage)

Comment: I have did a test using bind_param and fetch with a pre-selected request and got the correct variables, used the same request with get_result and got nothing. As explained though the request is never the same(dynamically sent via another script) so will not work for me...

Comment: Does `mysqlnd` show up when you call `phpinfo()`? Also make sure that error reporting is enabled and set to `E_ALL`

Comment: mysqlnd shows up enabled and I just updated the php.ini to E_ALL & E_NOTICE. Still no error message but it is possible it has to refresh

Comment: Still no error even with error_reporting set to E_ALL. The Mysqlnd shows up enabled running version 5.0.10. I am lost here it seems like a pretty basic function(get_result) and I can't understand why the hosting provider(or CPANEL) wouldn't be able to enable it...If I can just get another hosting provider that support the custom extension I will move the site and be done with this. Thanks a lot for any help...

Answer (score 1):

Since I couldn't find an answer I decided to change my code to use PDO instead of mysqli. It worked perfectly. I can't send you to a proper tutorial since I speak french and read mine in french. But a lot of resources are out there to use the PDO. It is pretty ease. Hope this helps.

Comment: That was a good idea of yours. As of the tutorial, I wrote a good one, [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), so you can recommend this one :)